# Why can't I create a logical partition with `gparted`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to create a logical partition inside an extended partition but `gparted` doesn't let me do it.

My setup:

- System: Ubuntu 16.04
- Partitioning software: `gparted` 0.25.0

HDD 1TB

- `/dev/sda1`: extended partition (covers all the space)

  - `/dev/sda6`: 32GiB system root partition
  - `/dev/sda7`: 113GiB data partition
  - `/dev/sda5`: 664GiB main data partition
  - **114GiB Free space I want to use** as new partition, **not** as a part of `sda5`
  - `/dev/sda8`: 8GiB swap

Do I have to `umount` the system root partition?

Is there a workaround?

Is it just a bug?

**Why does this happen?**

I don't want to run a live CD/USB just to create a partition.

Yes, I know partition numbers are not ordered, but I'm using UUID anyway so who cares. I also know there are almost 70GB missing. This is because GiB is not equal to GB, and the brands sell HDD with measuring unit of 10^12 bytes instead of 2^40 bytes.

Comment: How exactly `gparted` doesn't let you? Have you tried other tools (like `fdisk`, `gdisk`)?

Comment: Please leave this question open (don't accept your own answer), so maybe someone will eventually explain to us what happened. I find it interesting. I have changed the question title and emphasized the "why?" part.

Comment: maybe the correct question should be something like: why do logical partitions need a 1MB gap at each side in `gparted`?

Comment: this might have nothing to do with not using live session. from a live usb i had the same problem and solved in the same way.

Comment: [When do logical partitions happen to need 1MB gap at each side in gparted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/438773/32012) on unix.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. All I've done is letting 1MB gap at each side of the partition and setting align to 'none'.

Still I don't understand why this is necessary.

Comment: +1 Although this short answer gives a workaround only and explains nothing, I appreciate it could be a life-saver for someone with similar problem.

Comment: How have you found about this trick? --- As it is the answer was short but efficient for me too (after solus linux failing to format and install on that partition; worked after formatting it in gparted as you said). - **Only I wasn't able to format from a live usb, until I used those settings. This might have nothing to do with being in live session or not**.

Comment: @cipricus I had an intuition and tried it out.

Comment: Sometimes trying out is easier than read lot's of documentation and sourcecode. On the other hand just tring things can be dangerous.

Comment: the possible question that you phrased in a past comment : - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/438773/32012